# Serving static files outside of wwwroot?

Tags: c#, .net-core

below is the code used for Serving Static Files Outside of wwwroot
//Serving Static Files Outside of wwwroot

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseClientStaticResources(this IApplicationBuilder app, HostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration Configuration, string site)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "sites/client1/web/assets"); // this allows for serving up contents in a folder named 'static'
        var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path);
        var options = new StaticFileOptions();
        options.RequestPath = ""; // an empty string will give the *appearance* of it being served up from the root
                                  //options.RequestPath = "/content"; // this will use the URL path named content, but could be any made-up name you want
        options.FileProvider = provider;
        app.UseStaticFiles(options);
        return app;
    }
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseTemplateStaticResources(this IApplicationBuilder app, HostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration Configuration, string template)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "sites/_templates/template1/web/assets"); // this allows for serving up contents in a folder named 'static'
        var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path);
        var options = new StaticFileOptions();
        options.RequestPath = ""; // an empty string will give the *appearance* of it being served up from the root
                                  //options.RequestPath = "/content"; // this will use the URL path named content, but could be any made-up name you want
        options.FileProvider = provider;
        app.UseStaticFiles(options);
        return app;
    }
```

in appsettings.json, we are defining structure like

```
"Multitenancy": {
   "Tenants": [
     {
       "client": "client1",
       "host": "localhost:5000"
     },
     {
       "client": "client2",
       "host": "localhost:6000"
     }
   ]
 }
```

and using

```
string client = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.GetTenant<AppTenant>()?.client;
```

I am trying to get the "client1" or "client2" based on the host URL we browsed in the UseClientStaticResources/ UseTemplateStaticResources extension methods.

How can I get Tenant Info in this using SaasKit?

Is this possible to get the context in this scenario?

Comment: `and is not working` what does it mean?

Comment: now check it once @Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: So are you getting error? What value you are expecting? What value you are actually getting? Where is this code `string client = context.ActionContext....` written?

Comment: description edited